# Firebase gets duplicated Data

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Every time I use the Method: add() I want to save Data into my Firebase db with a listener. The Listener gets the correct data at start, but when I add a something to my Firebase db, it will load all of the data again + the old one.

```
    init(appointments: [AppointmentModel] = []) {
        self.appointments = appointments
    }
    var db = Firestore.firestore()

    func fetch (userId: String) {
        db.collection("users")
            .document(userId)
            .collection("appointments")
            .addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, err) in
                if let err = err {
                    print("Error getting docs: \(err)")
                } else {

                    for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                        let d = document.data()

                        guard let name = d["name"] as? String else {
                            print("error name")
                            return
                        }

                        guard let time = d["time"] as? String else {
                            print("error time")
                            return
                        }

                        let appointment = AppointmentModel(
                            id: document.documentID,
                            name: name,
                            time: time,
                        )
                        self.appointments.append(appointment)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func add(userId: String, name : String, description : String, symbol : String, time : String) {
        let identifier = "APPOINTMENT_\(UUID())"
        db.collection("users").document(userId).collection("appointments").document(identifier).setData([
            "name" : name,
            "time" : time
        ]) { err in
            if let err = err {
                print("Error writing document: \(err)")
            } else {
                print("Document successfully written!")
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of calling `querySnapshot!.documents`, call `querySnapshot!.documentChanges`. This returns a list of document changes (either `.added`, `.modified`, or `.removed`, and allows you to add, remove, or modify them in your local array as needed.

Also, you can call `addDocument` instead of creating your own `UUID`.

**I've refactored your code for you, handling .added, .modified, and .removed:**

```swift
init(appointments: [AppointmentModel] = []) {
    self.appointments = appointments
}

let firestore = Firestore.firestore()

func fetch(uid: String) {
    firestore.collection("users/\(uid)/appointments").addSnapshotListener { snapshot, error in
        guard error == nil, let snapshot = snapshot?.documentChanges else { return }
        snapshot.forEach {
            let appointment = $0.document
            let appointmentId = appointment.documentID
            switch $0.type {
            case .added:
                guard let name = snapshot.get("name") as? String, let time = snapshot.get("time") as? String else { break }
                self.appointments.append(AppointmentModel(
                    id: appointmentId,
                    name: name,
                    time: time
                ))
            case .modified:
                guard let localAppointment = (self.appointments.first { $0.id == appointmentId }) else { break }
                updateAppointment(localAppointment)
            case .removed:
                self.appointments = self.appointments.filter { $0.id != appointmentId }
            @unknown default:
                break
            }
        }
    }
}

@discardableResult
func updateAppointment(_ appointment: AppointmentModel, snapshot: DocumentSnapshot) -> AppointmentModel {
    appointment.name = snapshot.get("name") as? String ?? appointment.name
    appointment.time = snapshot.get("time") as? String ?? appointment.time
    return appointment
}

func add(uid: String, name: String, description: String, symbol: String, time: String) {
    firestore.collection("users/\(uid)/appointments").addDocument(data: ["name": name, "time": time]) { error in
        if let error = error {
            print("Error writing document: \(error)")
        } else {
            print("Document successfully written!")
        }
    }
}
```